# Is it possible to have multiple prerequisite patterns in the same target in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have two targets like this

```
$(OBJ1): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(BUILDROOT)/proto/a/%.pb.cc

$(OBJ2): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(BUILDROOT)/proto/a/b/%.pb.cc
```

Is it possible to combine these two into the same target somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but you will need advanced make features (macros):

```
SRC := $(shell find $(BUILDROOT)/proto -type f -name '*.cc')
OBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC))))

compile: $(OBJ)

# $(1) is the cc source file
define MY_rule
$$(BUILDDIR)/$$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$$(notdir $(1))): $(1)
    $$(CXX) -c $$(CXXFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<
endef
$(foreach f,$(SRC),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(f))))
```

Demo:

```
$ ls -R proto
proto:
dira

proto/dira:
a.cc  dirb

proto/dira/dirb:
b.cc
$ make BUILDROOT=. BUILDDIR=build compile
g++ -c -o build/a.o proto/dira/a.cc
g++ -c -o build/b.o proto/dira/dirb/b.cc
```

Please have a look at the [section about the eval function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for a complete explanation.

**Late update**: one comment about your other (now deleted) similar question suggested to use the `vpath` directive. It is tricky too and adds an important constraint which is that all source files must have different basenames. For completeness, and assuming the constraint is satisfied, here is another `vpath`-based solution:

```
vpath <pattern> dira dirb dirc:...
```

tells make that when searching for a file that matches `<pattern>`, it must explore the listed directories. So, let us:

1. Compute the basenames of all source files and the corresponding object files:

   ```
   SRC := $(notdir $(shell find $(BUILDROOT)/proto -type f -name '*.cc'))
   OBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SRC)))
   ```
2. Get the list of all directories in `$(BUILDROOT)/proto`:

   ```
   DIR := $(shell find $(BUILDROOT)/proto -type d)
   ```
3. Now, we are ready to use the `vpath` directive:

   ```
   vpath %.cc $(DIR)
   ```

That's it. All in all, the following should work:

```
SRC   := $(notdir $(shell find $(BUILDROOT)/proto -type f -name '*.cc'))
DIR   := $(shell find $(BUILDROOT)/proto -type d)
OBJ   := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SRC)))

vpath %.cc $(DIR)

compile: $(OBJ)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Yes you were right. My previous solution did not work after I edited some files and ran make again. I will look into this solution. Thanks!